# procedure to rollback a transaction from audit table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, rollback, audit

I have created an audit table that is populated by an audit Trail (triggers after every update, delete, and insert) on different tables in my database. I am now asked to create a  stored procedure (script) to rollback the data change using the audit id. How do I go about do so. I wrote a script which seems good. The command is accepted by SQL Server (command completed Successfully). Unfortunately when I test it by passing the Audit_id, the command is completed but the data is not rolled back. This is the Procedure I developed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
create  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAudit_Rollback_2]
@AUDIT_ID NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS 
SET Nocount on

BEGIN
DECLARE  
@TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
@COLUMN  VARCHAR(100),
@OLD_VALUE VARCHAR(200),
@ID        varchar(50)

SELECT @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME FROM AUDIT;
SELECT @COLUMN = [COLUMN] FROM AUDIT;
SELECT @AUDIT_ID = AUDIT_ID FROM AUDIT;
SELECT @OLD_VALUE = OLD_VALUE FROM AUDIT
SELECT @ID  = ROW_DESCRIPTION FROM AUDIT;  

update [Production].[UnitMeasure]   
set @COLUMN = @OLD_VALUE  
WHERE  [Production].[UnitMeasure].[UnitMeasureCode] = @ID
END


[dbo].[spAudit_Rollback_2]'130F0598-EB89-44E5-A64A-ABDFF56809B5
```

This is the same script but using adventureworks2017 database and data.

If possible I would even prefer to use a variable to retrieve that table name from Audit and use that in the procedure. That too is giving me another error. 
Any help with this procedure will be awesome.

Comment: Use the passed-in `@AUDIT_ID` in the where clause of your queries. E.g. `SELECT @OLD_VALUE = OLD_VALUE FROM AUDIT WHERE AUDIT_ID = @AUDIT_ID`. Also, make all the individual SELECTs into a single `SELECT. E.g. SELECT @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN = [COLUMN] FROM AUDIT WHERE ...`

Comment: I made the changes -anu start suggested but no progress.

Comment: Please do `PRINT @OLD_VALUE` just before the UPDATE statement and find out if the SELECT query is getting the value you expect.

Comment: Print @OLD_VALUE returns the desired Value.

Comment: Ok. I'll post my answer so it can be formatted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be dynamic SQL because you're updating a column that's defined in a variable. Do the following in place of your current UPDATE statement.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000) = ''
SET @sql = 'UPDATE [Production].[UnitMeasure] ' +
    'SET ' + @COLUMN + ' = ''' + @OLD_VALUE  + '''' +
    'WHERE  [Production].[UnitMeasure].[UnitMeasureCode] = ''' + @ID + ''''
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thank a lot Anu Start. sorry I was working on a couple other projects so this one had to be postponed since it was less critical. It worked perfectly.